# Marklogic : Security and Configuration Upgrade message

Tags: marklogic

I had Marklogic  5 installed on my windows 7 laptop. I was then told the application in question requires Marklogic 4.2. I uninstalled 5 and installed 4.2. Started the server, and logged into admin page. I get the message

"This server must now upgrade the security database and configuration files to the latest version.Once this is complete, the security database and configuration files will be incompatible with previous versions. In addition, AppServices databases and forests will also be installed and configured. Click OK to continue"

But when i click ok its stays put on the same page.

Any pointers to what is the problem?

Thank you
Sameer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstalling the MarkLogic program does not remove the configuration or data directory, only the application binaries and supporting files. So the 5.0 Security database is still in the data directory, and 4.2 cannot use a 5.0 Security database.

Most 4.2 applications will run fine on 5.0, so I would try that first. If the application only works with 4.2, you will have to stop MarkLogic, delete the existing data directory, and then proceed. You will know this is working if you are asked to re-enter your license key (you might want to save a copy of that from the old data directory).

See http://docs.marklogic.com/4.2doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/4.2doc/xml/install_all/procedures.xml%2328962 for more details.

Comment: yep it did work as you said, removing the data directory prompts for license. Thank you again!